# Pyspark: Read Parquet written with Pandas rise 'Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,false))'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I need to read Parquet files written by Pandas using Pyarrow ( I can't change it for now) using PySpark.

I used `spark.read.parquet` to read Parquet files but I got the `Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,false))` error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-10e38942d3ef> in <cell line: 4>()
----> 4 spark_df = spark.read.parquet('data/tests_dataset')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (69d72c9d10d9 executor driver): org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,false)).
```

I use the last version of PySpark `3.5.1`. I also tried with the older version `3.4.2` but got the same error.

Searching online someone suggests to change the type of the DateTime on the Pandas' writing phase but I can't do that now. There is a way to avoid this problem without changing the parquet files?